Использование NuGet библиотек без интернета c#
ребят такая проблема, участвую в офлайн конкурсе, где нельзя устанавливать ничего стороннего, интернета попросту не будет.
интернет дадут только в первый день для докачки библиотек, у меня такая проблема что nuget распространяется только на один проект, то есть я не смогу устанавливать библиотеки по ходу дела. Как сразу установить библиотеки чтобы они распространялись на все решения? я уже много копаюсь с этим вопросом и не могу найти ответ

А что вам мешает, загрузить в один проект все nuget, этот проект на другие машины скопировать  или просто DLL вручную в каждый проект добавить.

NuGet поддерживает установку с локальных каталогов. Вам нужно добавить каталог в источники, через командную строку:
dotnet nuget add source c:\packages 

См. документацию dotnet nuget add source. Если эту команду выполнить из каталога без файла NuGet.Config, источник будет добавлен в конфигурацию компьютера и будет доступен для всех решений.
Далее, нужные пакеты скачиваете на другом компьютере, переносите на компьютер без интернета и кладете в этот каталог. Пакет можно скачать, найдя его на nuget.org и нажав на ссылку Download package. Если у пакетов есть зависимости, их тоже нужно скачать.
После этого вы можете их устанавливать как раньше, но они будут браться не с интернета, а с локальной папки.

Скачивать пакеты лучше через сам nuget. Команда dotnet restore --packages c:\packages скачает все используемые  пакеты и положит их в указанную папку. Потом эту папку можно добавить как источник пакетов для офлайн работы.
